# Flatlist item title display the previous items title property

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist

ı am trying to create a title property for my recording. When ı type the name of the recording, if it's first on the list the title property became blank. After creating the second recording and typing the name it gets the title of the **previous recording object**. Tried to change the calling **order of the modal function** in **stopRecording** function, but it didn't work. I hope you can help. My code is not clean for now ı will arrange it later, please ignore it

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
  FlatList,
  TextInput,
  Modal,
} from "react-native";
import { Audio } from "expo-av";
import { useState } from "react";
import * as Sharing from "expo-sharing";

export default function App() {
  const [recording, setRecording] = useState();
  const [recordings, setRecordings] = useState([]);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");

  async function startRecording() {
    try {
      const permission = await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync();

      if (permission.status === "granted") {
        await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
          allowsRecordingIOS: true,
          playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
        });

        const { recording } = await Audio.Recording.createAsync(
          Audio.RecordingOptionsPresets.HIGH_QUALITY
        );

        setRecording(recording);
      } else {
        setMessage("Please grant permission to app to access microphone");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Failed to start recording", err);
    }
  }

  async function stopRecording() {
    setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
    setRecording(undefined);
    await recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
    let updatedRecordings = [...recordings];
    const { sound, status } = await recording.createNewLoadedSoundAsync();
    updatedRecordings.push({
      sound: sound,
      file: recording.getURI(),
      id: parseInt(Math.random() * 1000),
      title: title,
    });
    setRecordings(updatedRecordings);
    setTitle("");
  }

  function deleteItem(id) {
    const filteredData = recordings.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
    setRecordings(filteredData);
  }

  function recordingView(item) {
    console.log(item);
    return (
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <Text style={styles.fill}>{item.item.title}</Text>
        <Button
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => item.item.sound.replayAsync()}
          title="Play"
        ></Button>
        <Button
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => Sharing.shareAsync(item.item.file)}
          title="Share"
        ></Button>
        <Button
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => {
            deleteItem(item.item.id);
          }}
          title="Delete"
        ></Button>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{message}</Text>
        <FlatList
          data={recordings}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
          renderItem={recordingView}
        />
        <Button
          title={recording ? "Stop Recording" : "Start Recording"}
          onPress={recording ? stopRecording : startRecording}
        />
        <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={true}
          visible={modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
          }}
        >
          <View>
            <View style={styles.generalContainer}>
              <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                <TextInput
                  style={styles.input}
                  placeholder="Recording name"
                  onChangeText={(title) => {
                    setTitle(title);
                  }}
                />
                <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                  <Button
                    title="Add"
                    onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}
                  />
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 10,
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  fill: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 16,
  },
  button: {
    margin: 16,
  },
  input: {
    textAlignVertical: "top",
    fontSize: 17,
    width: "100%",
    height: 40,
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    borderColor: "#ffffff",
    width: "100%",
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 15,
    padding: 10,
    color: "#ffffff",
  },
  generalContainer: {
    margin: 30,
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10,
    backgroundColor: "gray",
    borderRadius: 15,
    elevation: 4,
  },
  inputContainer: {
    padding: 20,
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});
```

Comment: Do you have a function to filter out the recordings based on the title? Because I'm not seeing any.

Comment: No ı don't have, ı don't need to filter by name. I just want to display my entire recordings data with name.

Comment: I will give your code a try, can you include your styles into your current post?

Comment: I add the styles and imports as well, have a nice try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your current code is that in your stopRecording() function, you tried to get the title by having the user key in the name from the modal but it will not work because that portion is synchronous meaning that the code below setModalVisable will already have ran before the user can even input a title. To fix this you must first get the user to key in the title before the recording can be saved.

I have modified the code to fix the issue.

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
  FlatList,
  TextInput,
  Modal,
} from 'react-native';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [recording, setRecording] = useState();
  const [recordings, setRecordings] = useState([]);
  const [isRecording, setIsRecording] = useState(false);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (!modalVisible && title != '') {
        saveRecording();
      }
    })();
  }, [modalVisible]);

  async function startRecording() {
    try {
      const permission = await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync();

      if (permission.status === 'granted') {
        await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
          allowsRecordingIOS: true,
          playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
        });

        const { recording } = await Audio.Recording.createAsync(
          Audio.RecordingOptionsPresets.HIGH_QUALITY
        );

        setRecording(recording);
        setIsRecording(true);
      } else {
        setMessage('Please grant permission to app to access microphone');
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Failed to start recording', err);
    }
  }

  async function stopRecording() {
    try {
      await recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    setIsRecording(false);
    setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
  }

  async function saveRecording() {
    try {
      // setRecording(undefined);
      // await recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
      let updatedRecordings = [...recordings];
      const { sound, status } = await recording.createNewLoadedSoundAsync();
      updatedRecordings.push({
        sound: sound,
        file: recording.getURI(),
        id: parseInt(Math.random() * 1000),
        title: title,
      });
      setRecordings(updatedRecordings);
      setTitle('');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  function deleteItem(id) {
    const filteredData = recordings.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
    setRecordings(filteredData);
  }

  function recordingView(item) {
    console.log(item);
    return (
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <Text style={styles.fill}>{item.item.title}</Text>
        <Button
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => item.item.sound.replayAsync()}
          title="Play"></Button>
        <Button
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => Sharing.shareAsync(item.item.file)}
          title="Share"></Button>
        <Button
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => {
            deleteItem(item.item.id);
          }}
          title="Delete"></Button>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{message}</Text>
        <FlatList
          data={recordings}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
          renderItem={recordingView}
        />
        <Button
          title={isRecording ? 'Stop Recording' : 'Start Recording'}
          onPress={isRecording ? stopRecording : startRecording}
        />
        <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={true}
          visible={modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
          }}>
          <View>
            <View style={styles.generalContainer}>
              <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                <TextInput
                  style={styles.input}
                  placeholder="Recording name"
                  onChangeText={(title) => {
                    setTitle(title);
                  }}
                />
                <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                  <Button
                    title="Add"
                    onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}
                  />
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 10,
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  fill: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 16,
  },
  button: {
    margin: 16,
  },
  input: {
    textAlignVertical: 'top',
    fontSize: 17,
    width: '100%',
    height: 40,
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    borderColor: '#ffffff',
    width: '100%',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 15,
    padding: 10,
    color: '#ffffff',
  },
  generalContainer: {
    margin: 30,
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'gray',
    borderRadius: 15,
    elevation: 4,
  },
  inputContainer: {
    padding: 20,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort it works perfectly. It really makes sense to use SaveRecording as a separate function. The only thing that ı need to fix is, with this code it stops recording after typing the name and pressing "ADD". So ı add the  "recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();" directly into the stopRecording().

Comment: Ah my bad on that, but I don't think  you can still use recording to check if it's still recording since the recording will only become undefined after user has keyed in the title. I suggest making a isRecording state and stop the recording in the stopRecording function. I have edited the code to handle this.